# JavaScript search not allowing for zero

Tags: javascript

Please see the [**Sample Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/SDM26/embedded/result/)

If you enter either of the example codes in the search box, you'll get a result that pops up in a jQuery UI Dialog.

The first example is **006**.

**Here's the code...**

```
if (ccode == 006) {
    sarcomment = '006';
    sardefinition = 'If you need to make corrections to your information, you may either make them online at www.fafsa.gov, or by using this SAR. You must use your Federal Student Aid PIN to access your record online. If you need additional help with your SAR, contact your school’s financial aid office or visit www.fafsa.gov and click the “Help” icon on the FAFSA home page. If your mailing address or e-mail address changes, you can make the correction online or send in the correction on your SAR. ';
    saractionneeded = 'N/A';
}
```

Immediately after that, you'll see the code for code **030**.

**Here's the code...**

```
if (ccode == 030) {
    sarcomment = '030';
    sardefinition = 'We are unable to read all of the information on your FAFSA or SAR because it was damaged. Please review all of the items on this SAR and make any corrections as needed.';
    saractionneeded = 'N/A';
}
```

The set up for the code 006 and 030 are the same. What I've learned here is that any of these search criteria that I create that ends with a 0 (zero), will result in an undefined query.

Not sure how to resolve this and seeking your assistance.

Comment: Always include the relevant code **in the question itself**, don't just link. A fiddle is a nice *addition*, not a substitute.

Comment: `030` is being read as an octal (base 8) number.  The leading `0` tells JavaScript to do that.  http://es5.github.io/#B.1.1

Comment: Values you get from DOM elements will always be strings. Comparing those to numeric constants is not the best idea.  I would structure the entire thing differently: use the code values (the strings from the input field) as a key on an object to look up a set of properties to assign values instead of that ugly series of `if` statements.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - The relevant code is right there? Why did you downvote?

Comment: @webfrogs that's not all the "relevant code". When you come here to ask a question, you shouldn't make the assumption that you fully understand what's going on. In this case, the key issue is that the value of "ccode" is a string pulled from the DOM, and not a number.

Comment: @webfrogs: The relevant code would, to pick a random example, show us where `ccode` comes from. Separately: You have no idea who downvoted the question. You know only that *someone* did, and that I commented. Making the assumption that those two people are the same person is a bad idea. You'll be wrong at least as often as you're right.

Comment: I'm still new to JS and didn't realize what all the **relevant code** is. Sorry guys... doing my best here. I guess that's why I'm here.

Comment: @Pointy - " I would structure the entire thing differently: use the code values (the strings from the input field) as a key on an object to look up a set of properties to assign values instead of that ugly series of if statements." I'm not sure how I would do this, but can you elaborate on this one a bit? I'm very interested.

Comment: @webfrogs I'll add an answer, because it's hard to write code here :)

Comment: That's fine. Thanks for getting back so quick. Almost tweeted you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numbers that **begin with a 0** in old & backward compatible versions of JavaScript are **[octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)**.

`030 = 0*8^2 + 3*8^1 + 0*8^0 = 24`

[Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) turns octal numbers into a syntax error

Comment: To be clear, that's only true on engines that [extend JavaScript to add octal literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1). JavaScript isn't specified to have them, and in fact, engines are [expressly forbidden from adding them in strict mode](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-C).

Comment: @JacobKrall - So, would `if (ccode == 030) {` have to be laid out like you suggested Jacob... a math formula? A little lost on how to implement this solution. I understand the math, just not quite how to put it to use.

Comment: Just use the text literal '030' for comparison (instead of a _number_), and you should be fine.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. This is how the text literal would be laid out... `if (ccode == '030') {` Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion for cleaning up that code. Instead of a long train of `if` statements — each one of which provides a chance for some subtle bug to creep in — you could instead use an object to map codes onto blocks of information. That would look something like this:

```
function showc_code(ccode){
  var codeTable = {
    '006': {
      definition: 'If you need to make corrections to your information, you may either make them online at www.fafsa.gov, or by using this SAR. You must use your Federal Student Aid PIN to access your record online. If you need additional help with your SAR, contact your school’s financial aid office or visit www.fafsa.gov and click the “Help” icon on the FAFSA home page. If your mailing address or e-mail address changes, you can make the correction online or send in the correction on your SAR. ',
      action: 'N/A'
    },
    '030': {
      definition: 'We are unable to read all of the information on your FAFSA or SAR because it was damaged. Please review all of the items on this SAR and make any corrections as needed.',
      action: 'N/A'
    },
    '040': {
      definition: 'Whatever',
      action: 'Something something'
    },
     // ... other codes ...
  };

  if (codeTable[ccode] != null) {
    sarcomment = ccode;
    sardefinition = codeTable[ccode].definition;
    saractionneeded  = codeTable[ccode].action;
  }
  else {
    // unknown code ... do whatever
  }

  // ... rest of your code to show the dialog ...
}
```

That way the mapping from code to relevant information is just data, with no "moving parts".

Comment: And you believe this would still load into my jquery ui dialog?

Comment: @webfrogs well it wouldn't change what you put into the dialog at all; the difference would be how you determine those "definition" and "action" fields.

Comment: Been trying to implement your suggestion. [**This is what I get though**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/SDM26/9/)... All the variables appear to match up.

Comment: Well you seem to have lost your variable declarations somewhere along the way. If you check the browser console, you're getting errors from that "onkeypress" handler that tries to call "isNumber", and also an error about "sardoc1" not being defined.

Comment: That was it. My epic failure. This [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/SDM26/17/) is good.